# Colab pro plus notebook disconnected after 13 hours of training

Tags: google-colaboratory

I took the colab pro plus offer and last night I wanted to train a model for 15 hours. But the notebook is disconnected after 13 hours. So I lost all my checkpoints and I have to start training again. I took the colab pro plus offer to avoid these inconveniences. How is it that this happened despite the colab pro plus offer? What can I do to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Have you contacted them? This seems to be a product support issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic